# Unable to wire UI Text object to C# Script

Tags: unity, gameobject, text, ui-design, unity-ui

I have created UI text object

[image]

And then created `Text` field in behavior class:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Explorer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material mat;
    public Text text;

...

void FixedUpdate () {
    ...
    text.text = string.Format("x {0}", scale);
```

If I just run it, it says

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

at runtime.

If I try to drag `ZoomText` to `Text` slot, it doesn't allow me:

[image]

If I first drag `ZoomText` from `Hierarchy` to `Project`

[image]

then it allows me to set `Text` slot, but still gives

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

at runtime.

If I am trying to set `text` field by `Find`

```
private void Start()
{
    text = (Text) GameObject.Find("ZoomText");
}
```

it gives me

```
Cannot convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.UI.Text'
```

What I am doing wrong? Suspect may be incorrect types, but how to know correct ones?

---

[image]

Comment: Could you show the full ZoomText in the inspector?

Comment: In your Explorer class, you can take a GameObject instead of a Text, than in your Start/Awake, just call a GetComponent<WhateverYourTypeIs>() on it.

Comment: @Zibelas see my update pls

Comment: @formatc2013 this worked, but why so complex? why was I able to set material directly?

Comment: [An object in your project folder cannot reference an object in your scene](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/135209/39518) - because scenes can come and go from memory, so you have no guarantee that scene object even exists when you want to read it. Object in the scene can reference each other, or objects in the project folder, but not the other way around.

Comment: Are you trying to drag your ZoomText on the script itself from Project? I am not sure if that is going to work you can drag it to Prefabs or GameObjects but not scripts!